# Creating pytorch Tensors from `torch` or `numpy` vectors

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to create some testing `torch` tensors by assembling the dimensions from vectors calculated via basic math functions. As a precursor: assembling Tensors from primitive python `arrays` does work:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
torch.Tensor([[1.0, 0.8, 0.6],[0.0, 0.5, 0.75]])
>> tensor([[1.0000, 0.8000, 0.6000],
            [0.0000, 0.5000, 0.7500]])
```

In addition we can assemble Tensors from `numpy` arrays
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html:

```
torch.tensor(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

However assembling from calculated vectors is eluding me. Here are some of the attempts made:

```
X  = torch.arange(0,6.28)
x = X

torch.Tensor([[torch.cos(X),torch.tan(x)]])

torch.Tensor([torch.cos(X),torch.tan(x)])

torch.Tensor([np.cos(X),np.tan(x)])

torch.Tensor([[np.cos(X),np.tan(x)]])

torch.Tensor(np.array([np.cos(X),np.tan(x)]))
```

All of the above have the following error:

> ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars

What is the correct syntax?

**Update** A comment requested showing `x` / `X`.  They're actually set to the same (I changed mind mid-course which to use)

```
In [56]: x == X                                                                                                                          
Out[56]: tensor([True, True, True, True, True, True, True])

In [51]:  x                                                                                                                              
Out[51]: tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])

In [52]: X                                                                                                                               
Out[52]: tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

Comment: Please let us know what values of `x` and `X` you use while assembling from calculated vectors. You probably have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @SVPraveen  Added `x`/`X` values  to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.arange` returns a torch.Tensor as seen below -

```
X  = torch.arange(0,6.28)
x
>> tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

Similarly, `torch.cos(x)` and `torch.tan(x)` returns instances of torch.Tensor

The ideal way to concatenate a sequence of tensors in torch is to use `torch.stack`

```
torch.stack([torch.cos(x), torch.tan(x)])
```

Output

```
>> tensor([[ 1.0000,  0.5403, -0.4161, -0.9900, -0.6536,  0.2837,  0.9602],
        [ 0.0000,  1.5574, -2.1850, -0.1425,  1.1578, -3.3805, -0.2910]])
```

If you prefer to concatenate along axis=0, use `torch.cat([torch.cos(x), torch.tan(x)])` instead.